# Sharing text to WhatsApp having 2000 to 3000 characters in hindi font

Tags: android

I am trying to share a big text having a length of more than 3000 characters. However, I am unable to send all the text to WhatsApp.

My code shares only approximately 1000 characters to WhatsApp.

Here is the code:

```
Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,data);
```

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: This is my code  : Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
  whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,data); this.startActivity(whatsappIntent)

Comment: Actually this problem occurred when i use hindi fonts.

Answer (score 5):

```
try{
        Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("whatsapp://send?text="+text+""); 
        Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);  
        startActivity(launchBrowser);
    }
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Whatsapp Not Installed.", 2000).show();
    }
```

I was facing the same problem with Arabic text. Use this code. it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know which method you are using but there is 2 methods and there is not a character limitation for these 2 methods. You can read and learn much about these methods:

1. [WhatsApp FAQ - I'm an Android Developer, how can I integrate WhatsApp with my app?](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/28000012)
2. [Android Developers page - Sending Simple Data to Other Apps](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html)

Good luck.