# Sharing Unicode text via Android Intent gets truncated on Whatsapp

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp

I am sharing a unicode text from my App via Intent, so that user can choose to share text via Email, Whatsapp or any other app receiving text/plain.

**Text received by Whatsapp gets truncated** when text size is large (1000 char or more), however full text is received on Email and other apps.

I am sharing it as following, and have also tried Intent instead of ShareCompact but both works similar!

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()
            .append(service.getTite())
            .append(service.getTextBody())
            .append(service.getTranslations());

    ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
            .setType("text/plain")
            .setText(sb.toString())
            .setSubject(service.getTite())
            .setChooserTitle(R.string.share_prompt)
            .startChooser();
```

Is there any Max Limit on sharing text to Whatsapp or some known solution on how to share 1-2K unicode data to Whatsapp via Intent sharing.

Comment: I tried it myself with your code, the limit at 4096 characters for my whatsapp application

Comment: Thanks Hendra, yes i also did similar test, my text is mostly Unicode (only title string is in English/ascii), so two bytes per char for Unicode.I copied the truncated text from whatsapp, file size come out to ~3k - 3.5k. Wasnt able to count the characters, guess they are less than 1500 char.

Comment: can you can provide the text you passing?

Comment: You can use any Arabic/Hindi or other Asian/Latin Unicode text, it fails with  everything :( i found a similar isue posted in the link, their solution by posting as "whatsapp://send?text="+text); works, but then Intent is only passed to Whatsapp and Users loose the flexibility to choose Email or other apps. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620598/sharing-text-to-whatsapp-having-2000-to-3000-characters-in-hindi-font

Comment: Hmm, actually you can make "your own intent chooser". So if the package name that user choose is whatsapp you can handle manually and use action "whatsapp://send?text="+text

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("whatsapp://send?text="+text+""); 
Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);  
startActivity(launchBrowser);
```